# Commit files into another directory - version control for config files

Tags: git, version-control

Is there a way to automatically move some files to another directory before committing?

I want this to store config files that are different for each developer into a config-backups/{developer-name} folder, so they are version controlled but not overwritten each time someone pulls the remote repository.

Comment: Better solution is to have master config which is added in source control and local config(not tracked in git) which overwrite the master config if available.

Comment: I want to do it mostly for IDE config files, so it would be quite complex to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

git has a mechanism to run script files automatically before a commit occurs. see the pre-commit section of

```
git help githooks
```

then move the files back with the 'post-commit hook'.